# error on line 7 <SyntaxError: bad input ('=')>

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a= [1,0,1,2]

for i in a:
    if a[i] == a[i+1] and a[i+1] !== 0: ##getting error on this line
        a[i+1] = 2*a[i]
```

help im a newbie. getting a error. i tried a lot of things, any help is appriciated

Comment: **`!==`** should probably be **`!=`**. But that will fail too, as you seem to confuse an element value to its index.

Answer (score 1):

change `if a[i] == a[i+1] and a[i+1] !== 0:`
to `if a[i] == a[i+1] and a[i+1] != 0:`

Answer (score 0):

a= [1,0,1,2]

for i in a:
if a[i] == a[i+1] and a[i+1] != 0: ##change this line

a[i+1] = 2*a[i]

Hope this will work.